# Libcurl error in a Windows Forms Application in Visual C++ 2010 express edition

Tags: libcurl

I have used libcurl in win32 console application and it is working fine. I have followed instruction from here. http://theetrain.ca/tech/installing-curl-using-visual-studio-2010-beginners-guide/. Now I want to use Lib curl in Windows Forms Application. But it is showing some errors.

1>Read website app.obj : error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" void * __clrcall curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YMPAXXZ); calling convention missing in metadata
1>Read website app.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000011) "extern "C" void * __clrcall curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YMPAXXZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Readwebsiteapp::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@Readwebsiteapp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Read website app.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void * __clrcall curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YMPAXXZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Readwebsiteapp::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@Readwebsiteapp@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>C:\Documents and Settings\nemo1\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Readwebsiteapp\Debug\Read website app.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Please give me some advise to solve this problem. Thank you. My code is:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma once
namespace Readwebsiteapp {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(120, 70);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(120, 153);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(420, 337);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        textBox1->Text = "hello";

        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode result;

        curl = curl_easy_init();
     }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're compiling managed C++, your native curl calls need to be marshaled through p/Invoke.  It might be easiest to wrap these in flat "C" calls to make the marshaling simpler.  In any case, I'd use the P/Invoke Interop Assistant tool (http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) to generate the necessary signatures.